# How can I select a certain amount of characters from a string in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle

Suppose I have a facilities column in my table which has the data type of VARCHAR2(300), If I call a query that displays the records in this column and I have not used all of the 300 characters, all of the characters show using up loads of empty space.

Is there a way I can show the results based on the amount of characters used and not just show all 300 characters?

Here is my SQL code:

```
    SELECT Depot_Depot_ID AS "Depot ID", facilities FORM BUS;

    THIS IS THE RESULT I GET...
```

[RESULTS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miFJi.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: why can't you use TRIM function? It's very obvious

Comment: I have tried using the RTRIM function but I can't get it to work :/ still get the same result

Comment: This sounds like a SQL\*Plus issue, not an Oracle SQL issue. In SQL\*Plus, issue the command `COLUMN "Depot ID" FORMAT A50` (if you want the result to be in a column of width 50). Do not end the command with a semicolon `;`, as this is a SQL\*Plus command, it is not a SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Oracle to test but this may work

```
declare maxlen number
SELECT max(LENGTH(TRIM(facilities))) INTO maxlen FROM BUS;

SELECT Depot_Depot_ID AS "Depot ID", cast(facilities as varchar(maxlen)) FORM BUS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i've found the answer I was looking for. Instead of TRIM or any of that I just use `SELECT CAST(facilities AS CHAR(80)) AS "Facilities" FROM BUS;` and it just displays the first 80 characters from the 'facilities' column